# How to prove that a function produces only integer results

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-writing, solution-verification

Given the sequence $a_n = 2^n-1,$ prove that $$\frac{a_na_{n-1}...a_{n-k+1}}{a_ka_{k-1}...a_1},$$is always an integer for $0\leq k \leq n$.

In other words, show that the product of $k$ consecutive terms of the sequence is an integer multiple of the product of the first $k$ consecutive terms.

What if the sequence is $a_n = n(n+1)$?

Comment: This is very confusing as written.

Comment: How is that a function of $x$?

Comment: I edited this to make it legible.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written the products down for some small values of $n$ and $k$ and tried to see a pattern or anything else helpful?

Comment: This is the number of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$, which is of course an integer.

Comment: For $a_n=n(n+1)$ consult [OEIS sequence A001263](https://oeis.org/A001263) "Narayana numbers".

Answer (score 2):

This is a special form of the $q$-binomial coefficient (special, because $q=2$ in the question), and these are integer, as described in gory detail here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: Do you know how to prove this from scratch?

Comment: The link gives (in essence) a complete proof via the q-pascal's triangle.